# Сбиваются стили шрифтом при обновлении странцы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста сделал два сайта выгрузил. При нажатии на логотип страница перезагружается, но почему-то возникает баг с шрифтами сначала один стиль отрисовывается потом тот который прописан. На gif всё видно. Из-за чего это может быть ? Или может это но[image: введите сюда описание изображения]рмально и не стоит с этим заморачиваться?

1) https://projectmogo.000webhostapp.com/

2) https://3dstudio.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Шрифты прогружаются не сразу, это нормально.

Comment: возможно у вас отключено кэширование и при каждом обновлении браузер заново загружает шрифты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На загрузку кастомного шрифта требуется время, поэтому пока идет загрузка отображается дефолтный шрифт, когда кастомный загружен - шрифт заменяется. Можно не показывать контент пока кастомный шрифт не загружен, но лучше так не делать потому, что пользователь вообще не увидит информацию до загрузки шрифта.